# Find an element with xpath misses a required positional element

Tags: selenium, xpath

I want to click on a radio-button in my html-file.

The following code:

```
from selenium.webdriver.remote import webdriver

element = webdriver.WebDriver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type='radio' and @name='AlarmMode']")
element.click()
```

gives me the error:

```
TypeError: find_element_by_xpath() missing 1 required positional argument: 'xpath'
```

Which argument is missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to first *instantiate a `webdriver` object* and then call `find_element_by_xpath()` on it:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(url)

element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type='radio' and @name='AlarmMode']")
element.click()
```